# How to maintain transparency when writing text on a Windows System Tray icon from unmanaged C program

Tags: c++, windows, icons, system, tray

I have a MFC C++ (unmanaged) Windows application that uses a “standard” icon in the System Tray.  This icon was created & edited using Visual Studio and is 32x32 pixels with only 4bit colour (according to VS's Resource Editor).

With Visual Studio, I also set a transparent background (shown as white in the “before” image).

I wish to dynamically change the icon by writing 2 digits (1-99) on top of it.

Using the code below (based on that in this question: [How to draw text with transparency using GDI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221322/how-to-draw-text-with-transparency-using-gdi)) to superimpose “55” in yellow on the icon, it works except that the transparency disappears (it appears black in the “after” image *and on the System Tray*).  My actual code differs very very slightly in that the font size (20), font name (Courier New), text colour (yellow - RGB(255, 255, 0)) and the numeric value (55) are run-time variables rather than fixed values.

Any suggestions on how to make the background remain transparent as far as the System Tray is concerned gratefully received.

These images have been captured using MS’s Snipping tool with the image open in MS Paint as a 32x32 icon wouldn't be very visible as-is.

Before Image:

[image: Before Image]

After image:

[image: After image]

Code:

```
void CreateNewIcon(HICON &hNewIcon, HICON hBackgroundIcon)
{
  ::DestroyIcon(hNewIcon);

  // First create font
  LOGFONT lf = { 0 };
  lf.lfHeight = -20;
  lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
  lf.lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_PRECIS;
  lf.lfQuality = CLEARTYPE_QUALITY;
  wmemset(lf.lfFaceName, 0, LF_FACESIZE);
  lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, L"Courier New");

  HFONT hFont = ::CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

  ICONINFO ii = { 0 };
  ::GetIconInfo(hBackgroundIcon, &ii);

  BITMAP bm = { 0 };
  ::GetObject(ii.hbmColor, sizeof(bm), &bm);
  SIZE szBmp = { bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight };

  HDC hDc = ::GetDC(NULL);
  HDC hMemDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDc);

  HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = ::SelectObject(hMemDC, ii.hbmColor);
  HGDIOBJ hOldFont = ::SelectObject(hMemDC, hFont);

  ::SetBkMode(hMemDC, TRANSPARENT);
  ::SetTextColor(hMemDC, RGB(255, 255, 0));
  ::TextOut(hMemDC, 0, 8, L"55", 2);

  ::SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldFont);
  ::SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldBmp);

  // We need a simple mask bitmap for the icon
  HBITMAP hBmpMsk = ::CreateBitmap(szBmp.cx, szBmp.cy, 1, 1, NULL);

  ICONINFO ii2 = { 0 };
  ii2.fIcon = TRUE;
  ii2.hbmColor = ii.hbmColor;
  ii2.hbmMask = hBmpMsk;

  // Create updated icon
  hNewIcon = ::CreateIconIndirect(&ii2);

  // Cleanup
  ::DeleteObject(hBmpMsk);
  ::DeleteDC(hMemDC);
  ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hDc);
  ::DeleteObject(ii.hbmColor);
  ::DeleteObject(ii.hbmMask);
  ::DeleteObject(hFont);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with our code:

- You are trying to draw cleartype-quality text over transparent icon part. But cleartype font rendering must be performed over opaque background because it needs to inspect background color. So you should switch to Anitialiased quality (or to not antialiased quality) or provide opaque background for your text.
- When you create `hBmpMsk` [you skip it's content initialization by supplying NULL for bits pointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd183485(v=vs.85).aspx), so resulting icon will actually have completely random transparency. You need to fill this mask bitmat appropriately.

Also you probably need to switch to higher bit depth because monochrome bitmap mask can't handle semitransparent parts of antialiased text.

**update**

I think you should draw cleartype text but with opaque background, then get text rectangle using something like `GetTextExtentPoint32`, then copy data from the original bitmap mask into `hBmpMsk` and then finally fill white (text) rectangle on it so the new icon will preserve transparency from original and has opaque text block.

Comment: With an icon this small in quality (32x32), I don't need clear type font and so I have now commentted out both "lf.lfOutPrecision" and "lf.lfQuality". But how do I "fill this mask bitmap appropriately"?

Comment: Actually tray icon size depends on system settings and may vary so you should retrieve required dimensions using [GetSystemMetrics with SM_CXSMICON and SM_CYSMICON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx). Commenting out `lf.lfQuality` make it contain DEFAULT_QUALITY (0) which does not necessary mean no cleartype. Anyway, I've edited my original answer because i'm running out of comment space.

Comment: Any chance of some template code for me to modify as I am not sure exactly what you are suggesting? As to icon size, this application has been running for years from XP to W10 with the current System Tray icon and I am just modifying it at run time and so I think I will stay with its current size. I can also look to change that once this is working for 32x32. Just tested: SM_CXICON = 32 and  SM_CXSMICON =16.

Comment: You should start by adding code to copy original mask bitmap `ii.hbmMask` content into new mask bitmap `hBmpMsk` just like you did with color bitmaps.

Comment: Changing ii2.hbmMask = hBmpMsk; to ii2.hbmMask = ii.hbmColor; before creating the new icon (effectively doing what you say without the intervening hBmpMsk) had no effect. Still black.

Comment: It should be `ii2.hbmMask = ii.hbmMask;` then. Assigning color bitmap to mask bitmap makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks - that change added transparency but, as you indicated, no text is visible where it overlaps the transparent part - i.e. where the first '5' overlaps the black in the original 'after image' above.

Comment: Just fill the text rectangle with white on bitmap mask. Black pixels of mask bitmap = transparent, white pixels of bitmap mask = opaque.

Comment: Easier said than done. This just overwrites that part of the icon with a white box:
  SIZE sz;
  GetTextExtentPoint32(hMemDC, L"55", 2, &sz);

  HDC hMaskDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDc);
  HGDIOBJ hOldMaskBmp = ::SelectObject(hMaskDC, ii.hbmMask);

  RECT rc; rc.left = 0; rc.right = sz.cx; rc.top = 8; rc.bottom = sz.cy + 8;

  HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
  ::FillRect(hMaskDC, &rc, hbr);

  HBITMAP hMaskBmp = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hMaskDC, hOldMaskBmp);

  ICONINFO ii2 = { 0 };
  ii2.fIcon = TRUE;
  ii2.hbmMask = hMaskBmp;
  ii2.hbmColor = ii.hbmColor;

Comment: Sorry - I thought I did as you said - update the bitmap mask not the actual bitmap? SO suggests (correctly) that this should really be via their chat but as it is an extended discussion but I don't have enough points to do chat. Email?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help from VTT without which I wouldn't have been able to get this far. This appears to work for me.

```
void CreateNewIcon(HICON &hNewIcon, HICON hBackgroundIcon)
{
  ::DestroyIcon(hNewIcon);

  HDC hDc = ::GetDC(NULL);
  HDC hMemDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDc);

  // Load up background icon
  ICONINFO ii = { 0 };
  ::GetIconInfo(hBackgroundIcon, &ii);

  HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = ::SelectObject(hMemDC, ii.hbmColor);

  // Create font
  LOGFONT lf = { 0 };
  lf.lfHeight = -20;
  lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
  lf.lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_PRECIS;
  lf.lfQuality = ANTIALIASED_QUALITY;
  wmemset(lf.lfFaceName, 0, LF_FACESIZE);
  lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, L"Courier New");

  HFONT hFont = ::CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
  HGDIOBJ hOldFont = ::SelectObject(hMemDC, hFont);

  // Write text
  ::SetBkMode(hMemDC, TRANSPARENT);
  ::SetTextColor(hMemDC, RGB(255, 255, 0));
  ::TextOut(hMemDC, 0, 8, L"55", 2);

  // Set up mask
  HDC hMaskDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDc);
  HGDIOBJ hOldMaskBmp = ::SelectObject(hMaskDC, ii.hbmMask);

  // Also write text on here
  HGDIOBJ hOldMaskFont = ::SelectObject(hMaskDC, hFont);
  ::SetBkMode(hMaskDC, TRANSPARENT);
  ::SetTextColor(hMaskDC, RGB(255, 255, 0));
  ::TextOut(hMaskDC, 0, 8, L"55", 2);

  // Get handle to create mask bitmap
  HBITMAP hMaskBmp = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hMaskDC, hOldMaskBmp);

  // Use new icon bitmap with text and new mask bitmap with text
  ICONINFO ii2 = { 0 };
  ii2.fIcon = TRUE;
  ii2.hbmMask = hMaskBmp;
  ii2.hbmColor = ii.hbmColor;

  // Create updated icon
  hNewIcon = ::CreateIconIndirect(&ii2);

  // Cleanup bitmap mask
  ::DeleteObject(hMaskBmp);
  ::DeleteDC(hMaskDC);

  // Cleanup font
  ::SelectObject(hMaskDC, hOldMaskFont);
  ::SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldFont);
  ::DeleteObject(hFont);

  // Release background bitmap
  ::SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldBmp);

  // Delete background icon bitmap info
  ::DeleteObject(ii.hbmColor);
  ::DeleteObject(ii.hbmMask);

  ::DeleteDC(hMemDC);
  ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hDc);
}
```